# List of structure in C

Tags: c, list

I want to create a list that contain a structure of person following FIFO.
I create a list with just 2 elements. The problem is when I printing my list. It prints three elements even if I create 2 elements.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct element element ;

struct person {
    char name[25], family[25];
    int age ;
};

struct element {
    struct person p;
    element *next ;
};

struct List{
    element *first;
};

int main()
{
    int n=2,i;
    element *pre, *actuel, *e;
    struct List *l=malloc(sizeof(l));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        e=malloc(sizeof(e));
        e->next=NULL;
        printf("give name:\n");
        scanf("%s",e->p.name);
        printf("give family name:\n");
        scanf("%s",e->p.family);
        printf("donner l'age :\n");
        scanf("%d",&e->p.age);
        if(i==0)
        {
            l->first=e;
            pre=e;
        }else{
            pre->next=e;
            pre=e;
        }

    }

   actuel=l->first;
   while(actuel!=NULL)
   {
        printf("age is : %d \n",actuel->p.age );
        printf("name is : %s \n",actuel->p.name );
        printf("family name is : %s \n",actuel->p.family );
        actuel=actuel->next;
   }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Where is the problem please ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you thing sizeof(e) is the size of? Hint: it isn't the size of an element.

Comment: In my C coding standard, although the language may allow it, giving the typedef element the same name as the structure is a recipe for confusion and problems - would always use a different name e.g. typedef struct element element_t;

Comment: Have you actually tried running this through a debugger? It's called debugging.

Comment: In Real Life, what is the maximum length of a name or a family name?

Comment: lol. It was just for testing @barny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to allocate for structure size, not for pointer to structure size.

`sizeof(l)` will return size of pointer to struct, while `sizeof(*l)` will return size of actual structure where `l` is type of structure.

Change these parts

```
struct List *l = malloc(sizeof(l));
e = malloc(sizeof(e));
```

to:

```
struct List *l = malloc(sizeof(*l));
e = malloc(sizeof(*e));
```

You can also do it in a way below but above example is more generic and avoids problems in future.

```
struct List *l = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
e = malloc(sizeof(struct element));
```

Comment: Yeeesss ! It was this. Thanks a lot

Comment: Personally I would prefer to leave the OP to figure this sort of thing out for themselves, preferably by breaking the problem down or inspecting it more using a debugger, rather than giving it to him on a plate.

Answer (score 0):

first error is this

```
struct List *l=malloc(sizeof(l));
```

it should be

```
struct List *l=malloc(sizeof(struct List));
```

because l is a pointer to a struct and pointers have a fixed size (depending on the architecture and independent of the object they point to)

same error later is actually the source of you problems:

```
e=malloc(sizeof(e));
```

it should be

```
e=malloc(sizeof(struct element));
```

Comment: Thank you of your remark but the problem still same

Comment: Why bother malloc the list? There is only one, and simply declaring a List l; avoids the pain and aggravation and risk of introducing errors that comes with using malloc - to be avoided.

Comment: I like how the guy snatches a solution and presents it as theirs and gets to be the accepted solution.